# calculating expression without using semicolon

Tags: c++, obfuscation

Given the expression by input like 68+32 we have to evaluate without using a semicolon in our program. If it will be something inside the if or for loop?
Reference : https://www.spoj.pl/problems/EXPR2/

Comment: Why was this tagged homework? It's a programming challenge, not homework.

Comment: @Shmoopty nah, it looks like the problem is to parse the grammar in C w/o using semicolons.

Comment: i didn't ask this for any homework. Morever i am a clollege guy

Comment: College students get homework, too.  Regardless, you should try working it out on your own: that's the point of a programming challenge. If other people do it for you, that doesn't help you at all.

Comment: i tried it using stringstream..
well i was unable to find out that whether we can declae sstream inside if or main function (through parameter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use if and the [comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) operator, something like this:

```
if( expr1, expr2, expr3, ... ) {}
```

It would be equivalent to

```
expr1;
expr2;
expr3;
...
```

To use variables without any warnings you can define a function the recieves the data types you need that you call from your main, like so:

```
void myFunc(int a, double b) {
    if ( expr1, expr2 ) { }
}
int main() {
    if ( myFunc(0, 0), 0 ) { }
}
```

Note that you need to add `, 0` in main, otherwise an error is raised because a void return is not ignored.

Answer (score 6):

You can use constructs like this:

```
if (i++) {}
```

However, that still doesn't answer how to declare variables.  However, one trick you can do is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(double x, double y) {
    if ((x = 1)) {}
    if ((y = 2)) {}
    if (std::cout << x << ", " << y << std::endl) {}
}
```

Sure, you'll get warnings for using the wrong types in the main argument list, but it'll work.

Comment: can we declare a variable inside if.

Comment: You can declare a variable inside an "if", but it will only exist in the scope of that "if".

Comment: sir i am getting problem in handling string using stringstream.