# defining stringstream and string inside if

Tags: c++

is there a way to define `std::string` and `std::stringstream` inside `if` or `main` function as a parameter

example

```
main(int d,int m)
{
if(std::cin>>d)
{}
if(std::stringstream ss,std::string s)
{}


}
```

it is giving the error

```
expected primary-expression before ‘ss’
error: expected `)' before ‘ss’
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: just trying to write a code without semicolon

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919574/ - why would anyone want to do this is beyond me though.

Comment: @alok that was my question only..
can anyone give a sslution plz..
i have been trying this for the last one day

Comment: @unknown: Yeah, the comment was directed to mch, not you.  If you've spent one day on this, you have probably spent 24 hours more than you should have on such a task. IMHO, your time is better spent learning doing more productive things.

Answer (score 3):

As this is C++ `main` must have a return type in it's declaration. The actual error that you are getting seems to indicate that you need to `#include <sstream>` at some point.

While you can declare a variable inside an if's condition expression it's not a feature that's used very often and the one object that's constructed must have an valid implicit conversion sequence to a `bool`. You can't use a `,` to attempt to declare two variables, it's not a valid expression for an `if` clause.

If construction of any object fails then an exception will have to have been thrown so this isn't a necessary or correct way to test for construction failure. You should probably just declare your variables in the function scope of `main`.

Comment: in C++ the "return 0" statement of the main function is implicit: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: @lx: Thanks for spotting the unclear wording. I meant something entirely different which I've fixed in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Anything returning any value like any function call can be done inside if but you can not declare variables in that, really silly.

This can be done as printf will return some value and if will check that return value for condition

```
 if(printf("Hello"))
```

but not this

```
if(std::string str)
```

Comment: -1, wrong. This is valid: `if(int fooResult = foo()) { ... }`. Works for any type that converts to `bool`

Comment: Here you are using a variable to save return type and then check that return type in if statement which is similar to what I have written in first if statement and what I said is that if(std::string str) is invalid and not anything like if(int a=getInt()). Understand first what I said and thrn comment as if(std::string str) and if(int fooResult = foo()) are different if statements

Answer (score 0):

The only valid pattern is:

```
Base* b = ...;
if (Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b)) {
  d->stuff();
}
```